# Solving algorithm for combinatorical OP (Multidimensional knapsack)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, knapsack-problem

I have created the following mathematical abstraction for an optimisation problem.

```
O - Order
C - customer
P - Producer
S - Productionslot(related to producer)

pc - Productioncost per slot
tc - Transportcost for an order produceded in a specific slot
a - Productamount per order
ca - Slotcapacity
e - Endtime of a slot
dt - Latest order arrival time
tt - Transporttime

Decisionvariables:
x - Produce in a specific slot
y - Produce an order in an specific slot
```

The following cost function has to be minimised:

[image: formula]

Meaning each order has to been processed in one production slot. Depending on the producer connected to this slot and its distance to the customer transportcost arise. If at least one order is produced in an slot, some sort of fixed cost for this production will occure. The aggregated sum of this costs should be minimised.

The following conditions apply:

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

This optimisation has to been repeated every day, with a different set of orders(o and a will vary).
Each producer will have 4 to 5 slots he produces in. The number of producers is 20. Orders are round about 100.

The last condition can be used to reduce the problem in advance. Meaning set all y's to 0 where the arrival time can not be reached, because arrival time is before productionend time plus transport time.

As far as I can see this problem and its size can not be easy used be just iterating through all feasible solutions. Even if you use condition 2 to reduced the combinations of "y" strongly, I will be left with approximately (5*20)^200 solutions to check(assign each order to each slot and check all combinations of order associations with respect to rest condtion fulfillment and cost function value).

If I do some mathematical operations I can form the problem to look pretty close to an Multidimensional Knapsack problem.
E.g. 
 - multiplie the objective function by -1 to have a max problem. 
 - Split condition 2 in two conditions to get less equal conditions(multiply the greater than with -1 as well)
 - Move the capacity term in condition 3 to the left side

But these operations lead to partly negative coefficient. Algorithms found in the literature to approach the MDK often assume them to be positiv, is that a problem?
Has someone a good branch and bound approach to capture the problem? Or do I have to use I Metaheuristic as often propossed in literature, and has someone used a specific approach to solve a similar problem before to tell me about his/her experience?

Has someone other moddeling tricks to reduce the problem complexity in the given situation.